How to solve "The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()." in python
I have a table that contains different columns. I want to create a new column "Outcome" based on conditional statements derived from 3 columns.
Columns: Column1, Column2 and Column3
New column to be created: Outcome
Column3 contains just two values: 0 and 100

My Code:
if ((df['Column1'] <= 10) & (df['Column2'] <= 15) & (df['Column3'] == 100)):
   df['Outcomes'] = "No Flood"
elif ((df['Column1'] > 10) & (df['Column2'] >= 15) & (df['Column3'] == 100)):
   df['Outcomes'] = "Flood"
elif (df['Column3'] == 0):
   df['Outcomes'] = "No Rain"


The error i'm getting: ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

I think you just need to tack onto the end else df['outcomes'] = "ambiguous". Your tests leave the column undefined along one path. If I were you I would test df[c3]==100 first and then split it. The logic error would be much easier to spot if you did it that way.

df['Column1'] is an entire column, containing many values, but you're comparing it to a single value.  The comparison (df['Column1'] <= 10) makes no sense, and the error message is telling you that.

The issue you're seeing (ValueError: The truth value of a Series is unclear) happens when you try to evaluate several conditions directly on the DataFrame, resulting in a Series of boolean values. To handle row-wise conditional expressions, use either np.where or the apply function.

Thanks all, i really appreciate......... The link @STerliakov share solved my problem.

np.select is intended for use with multiple conditions.
